# How to get the number of applications connected to each X screen?

Tags: x11, xorg

The X server has two GPUs (one X Screen per GPU), so there is `:0.0` and `:0.1`. On other X servers I'm launching applications with VirtualGL that points to the main X server. As a result, they run their GL on the GPUs. They don't create windows on the X server that holds GPUs.

How to find out from the X server how many apps are there running per screen?

The workarounds would be to ask the GPU driver directly, track the apps manually with some database, semaphores or a shim that creates windows on the X.